# can magento add store with different subdomain?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

it's my first time to use magento my main domain for exmple domain .com with centos OS my magento on store.domain .com with Ubuntu 16 can i use the same Ubuntu server for another store with sub domain store2.domain .com ? P.S my main domain domain .com uses wordpress Cms thanks

Comment: Yes you can use same same Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can either set up magento as a multistore setup (see http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html )

or you create another apache vhost and point it to a different directory

See here: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Apache/Virtual_Hosts/

If the stores have nothing in common, the second way is the way to go.